# how can we combine synchronous function, callback function and promise all together

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, synchronous

If I have three types of functions, which return, respectively,

1. A synchronous value:

   ```js
   function a(){
     return 'a';
   }
   ```
2. A callback:

   ```js
   function b(callback){
     setTimeout(() => {
       callback('b');
     }, 10);
   }
   ```
3. a `Promise`:

   ```js
   function c() {
     return Promise.resolve('c')
   }
   ```

How can I combine the result of all 3 in a single promise? Can I create a function which will return `['a', 'b', 'c']`? I do not want to change these three functions.

How can we combine a synchronous function, a callback function and a `Promise` all together?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? From your comment to CertainPerformances answer, why is there a restriction on wrapping the callback function in a Promise? This question lacks context.

Comment: I recommend you read up on [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s.

Answer (score 2):

Promisify the callback, and send all three through `Promise.all`.

```js
function a() {
  return "a";
}
function b(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('b');
  }, 10);
}
const bProm = () => new Promise(b);
function c() {
  return Promise.resolve('c')
}


Promise.all([
  a(),
  bProm(),
  c(),
])
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Comment: Do not convert b into promise too. it should be of callback type.

Comment: This will not work `new Promise(b);`. It won't wait setTimeout to execute the callback to resolve the promise.

Comment: @wladimirguerra Yes it will - try it yourself. Change the 10 to a 3000, and you'll see that it'll take 3 seconds to log instead of none.

Comment: Your are right, it will work. But not as expected. Where the `callback` will fit in? The `callback` arg must be another function besides a promise `resolve`.

Comment: @wladimirguerra I don't see any need to wrap the callback in *another* callback - given the code in the question, `const bProm = () => new Promise(b);` really is sufficient to produce the expected results. It looks odd, but given how the `b` function is formulated, it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

Sequential execution:

```js
function a() {
    return 'a';
}

function b(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback('b');
    }, 10);
}

function c() {
    return Promise.resolve('c');
}

function abc() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const valueA = a();
        b(valueB => {
            c().then(valueC => {
                resolve([valueA, valueB, valueC]);
            });
        });
    });
}

abc().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: This is the most simple and closest solution to what OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Given the functions:

```
function a(){
  return 'a';
}

function b(callback){
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('b');
  }, 10);
}

function c() {
    return Promise.resolve('c');
}
```

You can wrap them all in a promise using `Promise.all()`. The solution will depend on your requirements and limitations.

The `function b(callback)` must be wrapped, or be changed to accomplish this, because it has a `setTimeout` within it.

**Wrapped version**

```
function bWrapped (callback) {
    return new Promise( 
       resolve => 
          b(()=> { 
              resolve(callback('b'));
          }
    )
}
```

A function to return the expected result would be like:

```
const abc = () => {
   const functionAPromise = Promise.resolve(a())

   const callback = function(b){return b}
   const functionBPromise = bWrapped(callback)

   return Promise.all([functionAPromise,functionBPromise,c()])
}
```

**Changed version**

```
function b(callback){
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=> resolve(callback('b')), 10))
}
```

A function to return the expected result would be like:

```
const abc = () => {
   const functionAPromise = Promise.resolve(a())

   const callback = function(b){return b}
   return Promise.all([functionAPromise,b(callback),c()])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the result of each function and handle them.

```js
function a() {
    return "a";
}

function b(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => callback("b"), 10);
}

function c() {
    return Promise.resolve("c");
}
const functionList = [a, b, c];

function runFunctionList(list, callback) {
    const resultList = [];
    const called = {};
    function next() {
        if (resultList.length === list.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
                if (resultList[i] === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            callback(resultList);
            resultList.length = 0;
        }
    }
    list.forEach((li, index) => {
        const ret = li(value => {
            resultList[index] = value;
            next();
        });
        if (ret instanceof Promise) {
            // it's promise
            ret.then(value => {
                resultList[index] = value;
                next();
            });
        } else if (ret === undefined) {
            // it's callback function
        } else {
            // it's synchronous function
            resultList[index] = ret;
        }
    });
    next();
}
runFunctionList(functionList, allValue => {
    console.log("allValue here:", allValue);
});
```